# Getting google credentials for Youtube Data API in Flask

Tags: flask, youtube-api

I want to report comments using `markAsSpam` to YouTube comments where its ID's were extracted beforehand. The code below works but only in the terminal.

```py
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json', ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"])
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
request = youtube.comments().markAsSpam(id='some_id')
request.execute()
```

The `flow.run_console()` shows a link in the terminal where the user visits to copy a string, so it can be entered in the terminal where the process continues and the comment is finally marked as spam. How do I make this work in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a complete example from Google that I found:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_5

For disabling the OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally, there are several options answered in this other SO post:

[Testing flask-oauthlib locally without https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785375/testing-flask-oauthlib-locally-without-https)